# Проброс трафика через транзитный сервер

Tags: linux, debian, ssh

Имеется в наличии 2 сервера debian:

1. Обычный сервер, имеющий доступ из любой точки мира.
2. Сервер локальный, который может подключиться к серверу №1.

Как без «велосипедов» отправлять данные с сервера №2 в инет, хотя бы просто через rsync.

Если не понятно, то вот схема: Интернет <-> №1 <-> №2

Comment: Ну с rsync это как раз какие то жуткие велосипеды будут. проще полностью интернет прокинуть. Вот хотя бы, самое короткое что нашел за 2 минуты в гугле: https://debian.pro/249

Comment: это применение для локального сервера? или который смотрит в инет. Спасибо

Comment: Для инетовского. на втором просто добавляете машрут по умолчанию через первый. т.е. что то типа `route add default gw внутренний-ip-первого-сервера`. Посмотрите где это в дебиане задается, там наверняка просто какой нибудь конфиг где тупо адрес шлюза пишется и все

Comment: Почитал статью пару раз, но так и не понял, мы настраиваем форвадинг на тачку которой есть инет, потом прописываем маршрут на локальной, и это всё? странно.

Немного почитал другие статьи там через второй интефейс тачки, которая имеет доступ в инет(1 интефейс на инет, 2 интерфейс на локальную сеть)

Comment: Не совсем так, одних маршрутов и включения форвардинга достаточно что бы машины имеющие релаьные адреса пробрасывали через друг друга трафик. А т.к. у нас у второй машины не реальник и в интернете никто не знает где его искать, то бы добавляем одно правило в iptables с MASQUERADE что бы превратить внутренние ip в наш внешний

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то методов много, тут уже маскарадинг или НАТ подсказали.
Можно на бордере поставить прокси, например "носки" socks

http://www.stokebloke.com/wordpress/2008/12/17/ssh-and-rsync-through-a-socks-proxy/

Answer (score 0):

> хотя бы просто через rsync

программа *rsync* по умолчанию (без явного указания протокола) работает через *ssh*-соединение.

---

допустим, у нас есть:

- host1 — машина с *ssh-клиентом*, без какого-либо доступа к интернету и *nameserver*-ам, но с доступом по сети к host2
- host2 — машина с *ssh-сервером*, с доступом к интернету
- host3 — машина с *ssh-сервером*, где-то в интернете
- у нас есть логины/пароли для подключения по протоколу *ssh* и к host2 и к host3: user2@host2, user3@host3

на машине host1 надо добавить в файл `~/.ssh/config` следующие (абсолютно стандартные для проксирования) строки:

```
host host3
proxycommand ssh user2@host2 nc %h %p
```

теперь команда:

```
$ rsync user3@host3:/путь/к/файлу /локальный/путь/
```

спокойно скопирует `/путь/к/файлу` (находящийся на host3) в локальный каталог `/локальный/путь/`.

и наоборот:

```
$ rsync /локальный/файл user3@host3:/путь/
```