# подключение по цепочке серверов по протоколу ssh

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, shell

Необходимо запускать скрипты с сервера удаленно. Получается вот такая 
цепочка:
server1: вызывает скрипт, который командой ssh "server2" "script1.sh" вызывает другой скрипт. Далее на server2 script1 вызывает уже другой скрипт локально, т.е source ./script2.sh и вот в данном скрипте идет снова команда ssh "serverN" "script3". Но вылетает ошибка: 
**Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).**
Если запускать script2.sh с сервера, то он отрабатывает. Получается проблема в цепочке вызовов ssh.

Хотя доступ с есть, ключи на сервере есть. Не нашел ответа в гугле. Думаю что проблема в окружении, пробовал указывать ключ напрямую - не помогает. Как решить данную проблему. Буду благодарен, если посоветуете организовать централизованный доступ к скриптам каким-либо другим способом!

Вопрос решился подставление ключа -i. ssh -i.

Comment: `-A — Enables forwarding of the authentication agent connection` или то же самое [с помощью директивы `forwardagent` в файле конфигурации](https://debian.pro/567).

Comment: Агент включен! я же описал, что если локально запускать скрипт, он работает ключи пробрасываются и все хорошо, а если запускать скрипт в котором ssh sr1 script. scpript ssh sr2 то  permission denied

Answer (score 5):

конечно, лучше не «разбрасывать» секретные части ключей по компьютерам в сети, а держать их только в локальном (т.е., физически контролируемом) компьютере.

чтобы работать с цепочкой компьютеров, подключаясь от одного к другому-третьему и т.д., можно использовать два несколько отличающихся подхода (подразумевается, что публичные части используемых ключей уже скопированы на все нужные компьютеры, а все секретные части уже известны [агенту](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/469423/178576)):

1. воспользоваться настройками в файле `~/.ssh/config`, в частности, возможностями [директивы `proxycommand`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/501315/178576), и подключаться к нужному компьютеру в цепочке вводом всего одной команды.

   пример необходимых секций `host` в файле `~/.ssh/config` для цепочки `локальный компьютер → user1@host1 → user2@host2`:

   ```
   host host1
   user user1
   forwardagent yes

   host host2
   user user2
   forwardagent yes
   proxycommand ssh user1@host1 nc %h %p

   host host3
   user user3
   proxycommand ssh user2@host2 nc %h %p
   ```

   подключение к host2 (с локального компьютера):

   ```
   $ ssh host2
   ```

   подключение к host3 (с локального компьютера):

   ```
   $ ssh host3
   ```
2. «руками» запускать на очередном в цепочке компьютере программу *ssh*, указав параметром следующий в цепочке компьютер. если директив `forwardagent` в соответствующих секциях `host` не описано, то надо будет явно указывать опцию `-A` прогрммы *ssh*.

   подключение к первому компьютеру в цепочке:

   ```
   $ ssh user1@host1 hostname
   host1
   ```

   теперь ко второму (все примеры выполняется с локального компьютера):

   ```
   $ ssh user1@host1 ssh user2@host2 hostname
   Permission denied, please try again.
   Permission denied, please try again.
   Permission denied (publickey,password).
   ```

   опа, забыли про опцию! исправляемся:

   ```
   $ ssh -A user1@host1 ssh user2@host2 hostname
   host2
   ```

   добавляем третий компьютер:

   ```
   $ ssh -A user1@host1 ssh user2@host2 ssh user3@host3 hostname
   Permission denied, please try again.
   Permission denied, please try again.
   Permission denied (publickey,password).
   ```

   хм. ну, да, на host2 ведь тоже надо пробросить доступ к агенту:

   ```
   $ ssh -A user1@host1 ssh -A user2@host2 ssh user3@host3 hostname
   host3
   ```
3. (добавлено 2020-06-07) воспользоваться появившейся в [версии 7.3](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.3) директивой конфигурации `proxyjump` или сопутствующим ей параметром командной строки `-J точка-назначения[,...]`. подробнее см. [мой ответ на другой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1137958/178576).

первый вариант представляется несколько более лаконичным с точки зрения вводимых команд, но зато надо больше «писанины разводить» в `~/.ssh/config`