# Как подключится по SSH к удаленному компьютеру котроый в нутри локальной сети

Tags: linux, ssh

Модель сети
Роутер, от него идет кабелем интернет на другой роутер, и от это роутера кабелем идет интернет на компьютер. Айпи компьютера статическое. Если я буду подключатся просто по ip то я попаду на роутер(в теории). Можно пробросить порт на второй роутер, а от второго на компьютер. Или как правильно сделать? И как при этом будет выглядеть команда ssh с несколькоми портами?)) порт ссш на компе стандартный, 22. Дистрибутив Ubuntu 16 но сильно урезанная.

Answer (score 1):

На роутере который относятся к SSH серверу. Прописать проброс 22 порта с внешненго подключения на внутренний (локальный) IP компьютера не котором стоит SSH.

Подключаться просто по внешнему IP (к роутеру), дальше роутер пробросить сигнал автоматически.

Comment: Смотрите. Первый роутер который имеет доступ к интернету, это просто tplink. От него кабель приходит интернет во второй роутер. Второй роутер прошит OpenWRT. Там встроенный ssh сервер на 22 порту и так же там локальная сеть с дригим айпи идет. И только от него мне нужен комп...

Comment: Что то я не совсем понял идею. Интернет от провайдера приходит в первый роутер, от него во второй (с поднятым SSH), от него в компьтеютер?
То есть получается первый роутер имеет сеть от интерента, второй роутер в локальной сети 1 (от первого роутера), компьютер в локальной сети 2 (от второго роутера) ?
А на самом компьютере то SSH сервер есть?

Comment: извините, что может немного не явно излогаю свою мысль. Получается интернет приходит на роутер tp-link. В нем вроде нет ssh. С этого роутера по кабелю идет интернет на второй роутер. Второй роутер прошит под OpenWRT и нем есть ssh и он на 22 порту. И только от второго роутера по кабелю идет подключение к компьютеру, у которого айпи статический. На компьютере ssh тоже 22 порт. Если пробросить порты, то как указать их в ssh
ssh -p port_tp_link -p local_port -p port_computer login@ip_computer 
я думаю так не сработает)

Answer (score 1):

> И как при этом будет выглядеть команда ssh с несколькоми портами?

1. полный формат указания `точки-назначения` может содержать не только имя/ip-адрес компьютера, но и имя пользователя, и номер порта. пример указания:

   ```
   компьютер
   пользователь@компьютер
   компьютер:порт
   пользователь@компьютер:порт
   ```

   и даже так (правда, у меня не заработала такая конструкция внутри параметра `-J ...`, только в качестве конечной точки подключения):

   ```
   ssh://пользователь@компьютер:порт
   ```
2. начиная с [версии 7.3](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.3) была добавлена директива конфигурации `proxyjump` и сопутствующий ей параметр командной строки `-J точка-назначения[,...]`.

   пример подключения по цепочке: сначала будет подключение к `тн1` (синтаксис `точки-назначения` приведён выше), из неё — к `тн2`, из неё — к `тн3`, из неё — к `тн4`:

   ```
   $ ssh -J тн1,тн2,тн3 тн4
   ```

   конечная точка — `тн3`:

   ```
   $ ssh -J тн1,тн2 тн3
   ```

   конечная точка — `тн2`:

   ```
   $ ssh -J тн1 тн2
   ```

   конечная точка — `тн1`:

   ```
   $ ssh тн1
   ```

Comment: Тоесть что бы подключится по цепочке команда будет выглядеть так
ssh -J ip_internet, ip_local, user@ip_computer?

Comment: привёл пример для двух, для одной и вообще без промежуточных точек.