# Как реализовать перенаправление с роутера на клиент

Tags: ssh, router, client, virtual

На virtual box стоит две машины: router (192.168.2.1) и client (192.168.2.2).
Настроил проброс портов на router.
То есть, если я подключаюсь с Хоста(с обычной консоли на убунту к виртуальной машине router), я ввожу в консоль:

ssh user@127.0.0.1 -p 8653

После чего, я могу подключиться к клиенту(виртуальная машина client) командой с роутера (router):

ssh user@192.168.2.2

Как сделать так, чтобы я мог с хоста(с обычного терминала на убунту) подключиться сразу к клиенту одной командой?

Comment: [proxycommand](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/954092/178576) или [proxyjump](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1137958/178576)

Comment: Спасибо так и сделал