# Удаленная разработка через SSH

Tags: c++, ssh, развертывание

есть необходимость в удаленной разработке по SSH, используя Clion, Sublime или VS Code. Но проблема заключается в том, что нет прямого доступа к машине для разработки (приходится заходить на эту машину через мост, т.е. через еще одну машину). Вопрос заключается в том, что можно ли как-то настроить в конфигах среды или редактора, чтобы разработка шла через мост (промежуточную машину)?

Comment: Любая проблема со связью затормозит работу. Используйте **git**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, это можно сделать. Не уверен насчет clion, но вот vs code заведется (я почти   в таких условиях работал).

Самое первое, это нужно упростить подключение. На своей локальной машине в ~/.ssh/config нужно прописать это самое подключение. Можно почитать детали к примеру тут https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/234903/correct-ssh-config-file-settings-to-tunnel-to-a-3rd-machine

Скорее всего оно будет выглядеть где то так

```
Host server1
  Hostname server1.example.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host server2
  Hostname server2.example.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  ProxyCommand ssh server1 -W %h:%p
```

и после этого можно будет в консоли писать сразу ssh server2 и подключаться. Также сразу заработает и scp, что сразу будет очень приятно.

В vscode можно поставить сразу плагин от майкрософта remote ssh и сразу появится возможность подключиться к серверу и работать на нем (он подхватит ~/.ssh/config). Также, если удаленный сервер открывает порт, то vscode умеет его "пробрасывать назад" - суперудобно для отладки докеров и нод. Второй большой плюс, что многие плагины можно ставить "удаленно" и они будут работать. То есть, плагин будет работать на удаленной машине, а в редакторе будет выглядеть как будто локальный. У меня даже gdb корректно работает и позволяет все отлаживать. Единственный минус этой схемы - vscode установит свой "сервер" на той машине. Возможно, это может не подойти (политика компании или там сервер на устаревшем древнем ядре неизвестного производителя процессоров)

Второй вариант - поставить плагин ssh fs, и теперь в "проводнике" будут доступны файлы. Их можно открывать и локально редактировать. Иногда бывает достаточно хорошо.

Также emacs может открывать файлы удаленно, если настроено подключение по ssh. Но это на любителя. Не у всех пальцы умеют вытягиваться в достаточной мере.

А если все это не будет работать, тогда есть vim+tmux/screen. Очень и очень приятный вариант. Вполне хорошо работает, даже если через vpn нужно по ssh подключатся к серверу на другом конце мира и пинге в 200-300мс. Правда при таком пинге нужно сразу просить по доллару-два в месяц за каждую миллисекунду пинга. Но при определенной сноровке (пройденный туториал) работается вполне комфортно. Сам так работал около 3 лет.

Ну и как сказали в комментариях, может все таки настроить систему контроля версий, что бы сорцы были доступны локально? Правда, не всегда билд можно делать "локально"...

Comment: Для полноты картины добавлю, что иногда, если действительно нужно и политика не запрещает в явном или неявном виде, можно с сервера пробросить туннель к себе - гуглить по запросу reverse ssh. И тогда Вы будете коннектиться как бы к локальному порту, а оказываться при этом на удаленном сервере - как то так

Comment: [варианты подключения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/954092/178576)