# Перенаправить запрос через другой компьютер

Tags: linux, windows, git, сеть, lan

Есть два компьютера: Raspberry Pi (ос rapebian) и стационарный компьютер на Windows 10 в одной локальной сети. На компьютере с windows установлен VPN, через который осуществляется доступ к удалённому GitLab. На Raspberry Pi ведётся разработка проекта который базируется на удалённом GitLab. Вопрос: каким образом можно настроить эту систему так, чтобы можно было отпралять изменения в удалённый GitLab через стационарный компьютер с Raspberry Pi?

Дополнительно:

- VPN: ShrewVPN. Попытка настройки на Raspberry Pi ни к чему не приводят. Без графической оболочки (через CLI) клиент сыплет ошибками. Искал способы решения, но они почти все без ответа. На windows работает без проблем. Держать включённой графику на Raspberry Pi исключительно ради VPN - считаю некорретным.
- На windows 10 есть OpenSSH Sever, nginx. Есть возможность поставить\настроить любое другое ПО.

Comment: запустить любой HTTP-прокси на Win10 и настроить работу на Pi через прокси - подходит как решение ?

Comment: Как уже писал - есть nginx, который может работать обозначенным proxy, но не хватает опыта чтобы настроить это корретно. Прошу подсказать в какую сторону глядеть или статью. Буду рад любым вариантам.

Comment: nginx - это вроде бы обратный прокси. Я бы взял чего проще под винду, да хотя бы и [3proxy](https://github.com/z3APA3A/3proxy). А вот [git-пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/) использования прокси

Comment: Вот корректная  [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128035/) на использование прокси для прошлого комментария

Comment: [например](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/501315/178576). разве только в мс/досе может не быть программы netcat, потому [вместо proxycommand используйте proxyjump](https://chrigl.de/posts/2014/03/03/ssh-jump-host-without-nc-netcat.html).

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, бывает 'netcat` и в MS DOS. http://wiki.freedos.org/wiki/index.php/Networking_FreeDOS_-_mTCP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ оказался ближе чем чем ожидалось. Достаточно было сделать port forwarding. Ответом будет небольшая адаптация вот этого [ответа](https://superuser.com/a/1117711) (или прямая [ссылка на вопрос](https://superuser.com/questions/1117698/tunneling-git-through-ssh-to-get-past-a-firewall-port-specification-interpert)).

Для корректной работы озвученной схемы: `Raspberry Pi` `->` `PC with windows` `->` `VPN` `->` `External GitLab` - достаточным является перенаправление порта.

1. На `PC with windows 10` [поднимаем](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse) OpenSSH server. В конфигурации по пути `C:\ProgramData\ssh` подкручиваем настройки в файле конфигурации (уберите символ `#`, чтобы раскомментировать настройку):

   - `Port`, если надо занять другой порт
   - `ListenAddress` выставляем в `0.0.0.0`, чтобы можно было присоединиться с других адресов
2. На `Raspberry Pi` запускаем проброс порта на другой компьютер командой

```bsh
ssh username@10.9.9.1 -D 1080 -N
```

Где `username` - имя пользователя, под которым выполнится вход на `PC with windows 10`; `10.9.9.1` - сетевой адрес `PC with windows 10`; `1080` - порт, который будет прослушиваться на `Raspberry Pi`. Так же можно выставить флаг `-f`, который позволит запустить перенаправление порта в фоне (подробнее о флагах [тут](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/ssh1.html)).

Теперь можно выполнить команду клонирования репозитория:

```bsh
git -c http.proxy=socks5://localhost:1080 clone http://serverB/repo.git
```

Где `http://serverB/repo.git` может быть любым удобным адресом клонируемого репозитория, в том числе и `https`.

Останется лишь прописать для данного репозитория настроку прокси. Например командой:

```bsh
git config http.proxy socks5://localhost:1080
```

Внутри папки проекта в папке `.git` в файле `config` можно будет увидеть результат:

```bsh
[http]
        proxy = socks5://localhost:1080
```

Теперь, при необходимости делать `push` \ `pull` достаточно будет активировать проброс порта (или можно прописать [автостарт команды через cron](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-execute-cron-job-after-system-reboot/))

Comment: Windows умеет NAT без всяких OpenSSH. Зачем вы это всё нагородили?

Comment: Сделал как сумел. Если есть более изящное решение, прошу его здесь описать. Я открыт для любых вариантов.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1088309/windows-10-nat-port-forwarding-ip-masquerade

Comment: В случае использования перенаправления портов - имеем ситуацию, когда идёт перенаправления трафика с адреса и порта на другой адрес и порт. Винда "из коробки" не умеет в `socks5` proxy. Да, можно поднять ещё один сервер, типа [3proxy](https://3proxy.ru/), но зачем, когда уже есть готовое решение. Это удобнее, чем прописывать сотню правил (например, чтобы подключится дополнительно к корпоративной БД).

Comment: Вам нужен NAT, который делается одним правилом. Windows это умеет из коробки, как показано по вышеприведённой ссылке.

Comment: В приведённой Вами ссылке вопрошающий уточняет о схожем с linux функционале (`iptables`) и ему отвечают двумя ответами о перенаправлении портов (встроенная утилита `netsh` и сторонняя программа), что имеет ограничение, которое я оговорил в своём комментарии. Попробуйте одной командой `netsh` пробросить трафик на несколько адресов и портов.

Comment: Ну это же не дублирующий вопрос, ссылка для направления исследований, там далее ссылка на документацию Microsoft, утилита `netsh` выглядит таким себе швейцарским армейским ножом для управления сетевыми настройками в Windows. Но возможно я чего-то не понимаю...

Answer (score 1):

Ещё одним вариантом решения получившейся ситуации является поднятие `proxy`-сервера на `windows` и проксирование запросов с `Rapberry Pi`.

Есть простой и не требовательный прокси сервер для windows - [3proxy](https://github.com/z3APA3A/3proxy). В разделе [релизов](https://github.com/z3APA3A/3proxy/releases) есть скомпилированные версии. Программа портабельна и не требует дополнительной устновки.

Распаковав архив внутри будут ожидать 3 папки и несколько файлов. Нам нужна папка `bin`. Сервер работает исключительно через CLI, соответственно настройка осуществляется через конфигурационный файл. Внутри папки `bin` создаём файл `3proxy.cfg`. Подробные возможности о настройке можно почитать в папке `doc` из корневой папки (на одном уровне с `bin`). Внутри файла создаём простейшую конфигурацию:

```
auth none
log <path_to_log>\logs\3proxy.log D
rotate 30
proxy
```

Где необходимо задать `<path_to_log>` до папки с логами. По логам будет удобно отслеживать работоспособность сервера. Параметр `D` означает ротацию логов по дням. Параметр `auth` в моём случае выставлен в `none`, т.е. сервер не будет требовать авторизации.

Запускается сервер просто: в командной строке необходимо запустить `3proxy.exe`. Если необходимо запустить программу в фоне, то можно сделать это [предложенным тут](https://superuser.com/a/591084) способом. Открываем `CMD` и набираем

```
START /B "<path_to_3proxy>\3proxy.exe"
```

Где `<path_to_3proxy>` - полный путь к программе.

На `Rapberry Pi` в свою очередь необходимо установить глобальное прокси. Для этого находясь в домашней (`~`) папке редактируем файл `.bashrc`. Дописываем в конец файла строки:

```
export http_proxy=http://10.10.10.1:3128
export https_proxy=https://10.10.10.1:3128
```

Где `10.10.10.1` - адрес компьютера с прокси-сервером. После чего необходимо его активировать:

```bsh
source ./.bashrc
```

Прокси сервер очень легковесный. В оперативной памяти занимает порядка 1.5Mb.